# Jmeter - Asnc request

Tags: http, asynchronous, tcp, jmeter

How I can simulate the async request from a JMeter.

Send Request from Jmeter  --> Sent to Server --> Server give the acknowledge

Now how I can open a port or URL where the server can give me a response once he has completed his internal cycle/flow. and how I can read the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and write a simple [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) server in Groovy using [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) which will be listening to the incoming data and doing whatever you need to be done with it.

Reference implementation which prints received messages to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging):

```
def socketServer = new ServerSocket(1234)

while (true) {
    socketServer.accept { socket ->
        socket.withStreams { input, output ->
            log.info("Received message: ${input.newReader().readLine()}")
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how it looks in action:

[image]

as you can see when I send `hello` message using [HTTP Raw Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-http-raw-request-sampler-when-and-how-to-use-it/) sampler it's getting printed to the JMeter log file, similarly you can capture your server's callback, just make sure that the server can reach the machine where JMeter is running, i.e. it has [static IP address](https://wiki.teltonika-networks.com/view/Private_and_Public_IP_Addresses#Static_IP_address), incoming traffic to the port of your choice is not blocked by a [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)), etc.

Comment: why JMeter does not stop after getting the response in JSR223 and how I can run this script with my main HTTP request with 1000's of requests ?

Comment: Because `while(true)` is an endless loop, you need to exit it somehow, for example by closing the socket. With regards to 1000 requests - I'm not telepathic enough to guess what is your requirement and how do you differentiate each of these 1000 threads